# Show $f(x)$ is partial recursive using the

Tags: computability, recursion

So I want to show that the function $f(x)=0 $ if $x$ is even and not defined otherwise, is partial recursive using the $\mu$ operator (bounded search function, which is partial recursive).

Plan is to show $f(x)$ = $\mu y_{\leq0}[odd(x \dot{-} y)=0]$, where $odd$ checks whether the input is odd or not, and $\dot{-}$ is limited subtraction.

Not sure if it's right...

Comment: Why not recurse via $f(x) = f(x\pm2)$ and search for the initial case $f(0) = 0$?

Comment: @EricTowers Do you mean search for initial y s.t. odd(y+2)=0?

Comment: Why not search for initial $y$ such that $x+2y = 0$?